# Where to catch crashes in android application?

Tags: android, android-activity, uncaught-exception

I want to reset some shared preferences values when application crashed.
I know I can implement UncaughExceptionHandler and than reset the shared preference values in the uncaughtException method, but where should I implement it? In a class that extends Application class or in a class that extends Activity and why?

Answer (score 0):

Entry point of any android app is `onCreate` method of `Application`. So yes, you should handle it there.

Comment: can t I implement it in a base class that extends Activity? (in the onCreate method) ?

Comment: You can implement it where ever you want but then you can miss app crash. The most early method of app starting is `onCreate` of `Application`.

Comment: so resetting the shared preference values in this uncaughtException method inside class that extends Application should work. Shloud i implement the interface or just add the following inside onCreate: Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                // TODO implement this

            }
        });